# rails how to create record with id

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I'm using rails v3.0.9 and Mysql database.

I'm migrating the tables with existing data.

I've users table and all other tables contains the user_id column and now i need seperate the users into two (users & customers) tables,

So i need to migrate the new customers table with existing users records where the user type with customer

I need to create a customers table and set the id of users records with user type as customer, 
which will be easy instead of migrating many of other tables(**which is used only by customers**) by checking every record with user's user type and assign the new id of customers table.

Tables looks like

users table:

```
    id  |       name    |   ...
   ------------------------------
    1   |       aaa     |   ...
    2   |       bbb     |   ...
    4   |       ddd     |   ...
    6   |       fff     |   ...
```

customers table

```
    id  |       name    |   ...
   -------------------------------
    3   |       ccc     |   ...
    5   |       eee     |   ...
    7   |       ggg     |   ...
```

When i'm migrating users existing data

In my migration file

```
def up
  create_table(:customers) do |t|
    t.string :name
  end

  User.joins(:user_type).where(:user_type => {:type_name => 'customer'}).find_in_batches(:batch_size => 100){ |users|
     users.each {|user|
          customer = Customer.new
          customer.id = user.id
          customer.name = user.name
          customer.save(:validate => false)
     }
   }
end
```

Also tried

```
Customer.create!(:id => user.id) instead of save method
```

Is this correct?

Is there any way to assign the primary id ?

If i'm going wrong give me some suggestion to do it in right way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql allow to insert the record with value of primary id column.
In Rails, you can execute any sql query by supplying to execute method

For example:

```
sql = "insert into users(id, username) values(10, 'iam')"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```